# How can I remove mold from the outside of a DSLR body?

Tags: lens, cleaning, fungus

I have always been into photography, but did not have my camera out at all this winter. Got it out today and there is mold on the body of the camera, on the outside of the lens ring. What's the best way to remove it? Do I need it done professionally or can I do it myself? If so what is the solution I need? I've heard isopropyl alcohol or vinegar.

It does not look like there is any mold in the body itself (fingers crossed) or on any of my lenses that I can see.

[image: Body Mould]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read online [one thread on the photoforum.com](http://www.thephotoforum.com/threads/cleaning-mould-from-this-part-of-my-camera-body.121244/) that was successful in cleaning and this is how it was done:

> 1. Make a 50/50 water/vinegar solution.
> 2. After cleaning the mold, dry the camera under a warm lamp with a small fan blowing warm air into the body to make sure any drop of vinegar has evaporated.
> 3. Expose it to a UV light so that the mold won't ever come again.

P.S. Be careful not to drop anything inside [plus you could use H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> (hydrogen peroxide) as an alternative to vinegar but I wouldn't recommend it, as it could react with the metal (body of camera).]

Answer (score 2):

I have used rubbing alcohol to remove mold off my lens and camera. Works like a charm. Do use a Q-tip for fine areas.

However, to prevent mold from coming back I recommend getting dehumidifier packets and put them near your camera gear during winter time or throughout the year if you live in a humid area. This will suck the moisture out of the air and makes it hard for mold to grow.